# BERT get top N words for each category

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I trained a BERT text classification model with 38 categories. Now, for each of these 38 categories I want to find out the top N words.

To do that, I used sklearn's CountVectorizer to create a vocabulary from the training dataset.

I passed that vocabulary to the tokenizer and used those tokens to pass to the model and get the last layer activations. So now I have a dataframe thats `vocab x num categories` size.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd 
import torch, os
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification


if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    print('GPU:', torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")


# Define a function to compute the activations of a hidden state for a given input
def get_hidden_state_activations(input_ids, model, layer_idx):
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids)
        activations = outputs[layer_idx]
        return activations#.mean(dim=1)



# create the vocabulary
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), max_features=10000, min_df=50)
#     vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,10), max_features=200, use_idf=True)
vecs = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print('collecting frequencies')
dense = vecs.todense()
lst1 = dense.tolist()
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
print('sorting them around')

# get all data into a DF
df = pd.DataFrame(lst1, columns=feature_names)
df = df.T.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index()
df.columns = ['word', 'frequency']
df = df[~df.word.str.isdigit()].reset_index(drop=True)

# load models
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(TOKENIZER_MODEL_NAME)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_NAME).to(device)

# data and labels
data = df.word.tolist()
labels = []


# Convert the data to input ids using the tokenizer
input_ids = [tokenizer.encode(example, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='pt') for example in data]


# Compute the activations of the hidden states for each input in the data
layer_idx = -1 # Choose the index of the layer to extract activations from
activations = [get_hidden_state_activations(input_id.to(device), model, layer_idx) for input_id in tqdm(input_ids)]

# get all activations into a df
activations_df = pd.DataFrame([i.cpu().detach().numpy().reshape(len(labels)) for i in activations])
activations_df.columns = labels
activations_df['word'] = data
activations_df = activations_df[['word'] + labels.tolist()]
# activations_df = activations_df.set_index('word')
activations_df.head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[NeuroX](https://github.com/fdalvi/NeuroX) is one of the most powerful interpretation tools that finds the most important neurons and the corresponding words for each category. You can check this [toturial](https://github.com/fdalvi/NeuroX/blob/master/examples/End%20to%20End%20Example.ipynb).
For your case, you already get the logit for each word; you can get the softmax of the logits and sort them for each label. For example, when I try to Seq. classifier with these 16 words, while love and know are the most important word for the 'good' class, problem and hate are the most important word for the 'bad' class as seen in the [image]